# Android Activity not attaching to Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

```
        BattleFragment battleFragment;
    battleFragment = BattleFragment.newInstance("0");
    FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();

    fm.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, battleFragment)
            .commit();
```

The above code is what I used to create a new fragment and display it. However when I am in the fragment and try to get the activity it returns null. When I run isAttached() it returns false. Is there something I am forgetting?

Comment: `However when I am in the fragment and try to get the activity it returns null.` What does that mean exactly? Show us the code that's actually not working.

Comment: `fragmentContainer` should be `FrameLayout`. Please check that

Answer (score 0):

Try following code..
And use `FrameLayout` (fragmentContainer) to inflate your fragment

```
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, new battleFragment());
ft.commit();
```

and

```
public class battleFragment extends Fragment
{
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.yourFragmentLayout,container, false);
            //Your operations inside Fragment
            return view;
}
```